# Referencing Classes and String Use

Tags: c#, xna

I am using `enum`s to use on the main menu but I am running into an error, I have looked over this for a while and can not find what is wrong.

What I am doing is for each page for the menu I have a class holding the images and there rectangles. When the mouse is over the image and is clicked on it will change the string to a name to make the program do something.

#### The Problem

For some reason the string `mouseOn` will not change from `"None"` when my `TitleScreen.cs` updates. What is wrong?

TitleScreen Class:

```
public class TitleScreen
{
    Game1 game1;

    public void Initialize()
    {
        game1 = new Game1();
    }

    public void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();

        if (mouse.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed && game1.mouseUsed == false && game1.mouseActive == true)
        {
            if (play.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Play";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
            else if (title.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Title";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
            else if (options.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Options";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
            else if (quit.Contains(mouse.X, mouse.Y))
            {
                game1.mouseOn = "Quit";
                game1.mouseUsed = true;
            }
        }
    }
```

Inside Main Class:

```
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";

        images = new Images();
        startup = new StartUp();
        resolution = new Resolution(new Vector2(screenWidth, screenHeight));
        options = new Options();
        credits = new Credits();
        titlescreen = new TitleScreen();

        images.Content = Content;

        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = (int)resolution.screenResolution.Y;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = (int)resolution.screenResolution.X;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        titlescreen.Initialize();

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

Comment: You are creating a new Game1 object. Pass your current Game1 object to your TitleScreen.Initialize() method. Too bad this is closed. Try do this in your TitleScreen method: public void Inititialize(Game1 game1) { this.game1 = game1 } now you can pass your game1 to this object like so in your Game1 class: TitleScreen.Initialize(this);

Comment: @MennoGouw Your answer is correct, there is also a small problem that I fixed were the `titlescreen.Update(gameTime);` was called after the `MouseActive(gameTime);`, this made the `mouseUsed` false befor going to the if statement so it would not go through. (it was not in the question so you did not see this)

Comment: @KirkWoll I had fixed the problem 3 days ago, it has plenty of information to diagnose the problem, the problem has been fix. Only minutes after I had accidently posted this I had fixed this problem. I am no longer able to post questions because of this post which I had correctly edited.  Menno Gouw has given the correct answer and can not be rewarded because of this. Please take this post off of hold since there is no reason to have it on hold.

Comment: @RyanFoy, I am sorry this situatation has been an inconvenience to you.  However, there is not a whole lot I personally can do about it. If you want to see about getting any restrictions on your account lifted, I suggest you post a question on http://meta.stackoverflow.com and reference this question and explain your problem.

Comment: @MennoGouw You may now post the answer to the question now, I thank all the people who spent time to help me with this silly problem I made. Again, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating another Game object in your TitleScreen class. I'm not sure why you need your complete Game class referenced in the title screen, if it is just for input commands you are often better off to make a separate input class and reference to that. Anyway, if you want a proper reference to Game1 instead of a new one you need to do this:

```
public class TitleScreen
{
    Game1 game1;

    public void Initialize(Game game1) //Or (Game1 game1) both work since Game1 is a child from Game.
    {
        this.game1 = new Game1();
    }
}
```

Now when you call the Initialize method on your TitleScreen object you pass the Game1 object to it using `this`.

```
protected override void Initialize()
    {
        titlescreen.Initialize(this);

        base.Initialize();
    }
```

If you are actually checking for input in your Game1 class this does not get passed to the TitleScreen. The easiest way to fix this is to pass Game1 within your update method in the same way we did above.

```
public void Update(GameTime gameTime, Game1 game1)
    {
        this.game1 = game1;
        MouseState mouse = Mouse.GetState();
    }
```

Again, you need to pass this each update loop in your Game1 update method:

```
titleScreen.Update(gameTime, this);
```

I cannot guarantee this will work, you might just need a better architecture (just passing the complete Game1 object is not a good idea imho). When i need a specific thing out of Game1 i just create property for it and just reference that. I do hope things are cleared up a bit for you, it is much like you are passing on GameTime and SpriteBatch, you do not need to pass those on if you already passing on the whole Game1 object.